# How to use INNER JOIN correctly in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I get a syntax error in this SQL query below, where it tells me INNER JOIN is not correctly used. How can I solve this? Thanks!

```sql
select m1.player, count(distinct m1.species) 
from phonemon as m1
group by player
INNER JOIN 
select ti.title, count(*)
from type as t1, species as s1
where s1.type1 = t1.id or s1.type2 = t1.id
group by t1.title
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN` is an operator in the `FROM` clause.  `GROUP BY` is a clause that follows `WHERE` which in turn follows `FROM`.

Comment: Are you trying to use `UNION`? I think any basic intro to SQL would explain this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you! Now I know why I get the error. `INNER JOIN` should follow `FROM`.

Comment: @BillKarwin Not `union`, because the two tables I want to join have different attributes.

Comment: The select-list of the two queries you show above are actually compatible enough to be unioned. That is, they have the same number of columns, and I assume `player` and `title` are both strings, whereas the two `count()` results are clearly integers.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what is the purpose of joining these two queries. They appear to have nothing to do with each other. Have you considered simply running two separate queries?

Comment: When you post about a problem you have, please paste the error message directly into the post, rather than paraphrasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I join phonemon to species by type1 or type2 equaling id.  I group by player and sort by title.

```
select m1.player, count(distinct m1.species) SpeciesCount from phonemon as m1
join species s1
    on s1.type1=t1.id or s1.type2=t1.id
group by
m1.player
order by t1.title
```